# Understanding the binary representation of a float

Tags: c++, floating-point, binary

I am using the following code to print out a "binary representation" of a floating point number:

```
template<class F>
void printBinary(F value)
{
    std::cout <<
        std::bitset<sizeof(F) * 8>(*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&value)).to_string()
    << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    float f = 1;
    printBinary(f);
    f = 2;
    printBinary(f);
    f = 3;
    printBinary(f);
    f = 4;
    printBinary(f);
    f = 16;
    printBinary(f);
    f = 0.2;
    printBinary(f);
}
```

It outputs:

```
00111111100000000000000000000000
01000000000000000000000000000000
01000000010000000000000000000000
01000000100000000000000000000000
01000001100000000000000000000000
00111110010011001100110011001101
```

Can someone explain what parts of the output binary numbers correspond to what parts of the float? I would expect the first one just to be `10000...`. The second makes sense. I am confused about every output after that, especially the last.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not specified in standard, but all major compilers use [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) as the floating point representation.

Comment: "_I would expect the first one just to be `10000...`_" Why? It's not a negative number..

Comment: Because if 2 is represented by `01` then for 1 you would slide the `1` over making it `10`.

Comment: @zoecarver First bit is, typically (even in integer implementations), reserved for distinguishing sign. 0 = positive; 1 = negative.

Comment: Do note that `*reinterpret_cast<unsigned long*>(&value)` is undefined behavior.  It violates strict aliasing.  What you need to do to be portable/conforming is to create an integer variable of the correct size and then `memcpy` the float into it.  Then you can send the integer to `std::bitset`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're referring to IEEE754 binary floating point format, a 32-bit float consists of 1 sign bit, 8 exponent bits, and 23 significand (aka fraction) bits. Here's how one of your examples `0.2` get represented, as an example:

```
                  3  2          1         0
                  1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
                  S ---E8--- ----------F23----------
          Binary: 0 01111100 10011001100110011001101
             Hex: 3E4C CCCD
       Precision: SP
            Sign: Positive
        Exponent: -3 (Stored: 124, Bias: 127)
       Hex-float: +0x1.99999ap-3
           Value: +0.2 (NORMAL)
```

You can read more about the format itself on the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats and also the specifics of the single-precision format in: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning tools such as https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html or https://calculla.com/floating_point_numbers

Comment: David Goldberg's 1991 ACM article [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf) is also a worthwhile read.